# How does the following expression scale with respect to $\epsilon$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, perturbation-theory

Let $\mathbf{V}$ be a $2N \times 2N$ positive definite matrix.

Let $\mathbf{V}^\star=\mathbf{V}+E$ where $||E||_\infty\leq\epsilon$ and $|\epsilon|<<1$. How does the following expression scale with respect to $\epsilon$?

$\log\left(\max\left(||\mathbf{V}^\star||_\infty,\left(||\mathbf{V}^{\star^{-1}}||^{-1}_\infty-1\right)/2\right)\right)$

Comment: Which [matrix norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) do you mean?

Comment: $||\mathbf{V}||_\infty=\max_{1\leq i \leq m} \sum_{j=1}^{j=n}|\mathbf{V}_{ij}|$